# setprop/getprop

Tags: android

hi I am trying to modify values of some android properties. I am fairly new to this so I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

i am trying to modify the following settings
ril.MSL and other data settings for my phone.

question is getprop shows me the value of net.cdma.rtsp.proxy.addr 
but does not for ril.MSL.

it does allow me to use setprop on both these attributes but it seems like it does not let me change the values.

is there way i can tell which properties are read only and which can be modified? furthermore, without root access can i somehow read the ril.MSL? its hidden from me at the moment. If the property is read only why cant I read it?

also are there any xml files i can use to edit/set to get this info?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on the adb shell command line then you need a rooted handset and to "su" to root to be able to set a system property.